# Obtain features inside image and remove boundary

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect features inside an image (retina scan). The image consists of a retina scan inside a rectangular box with black background.

I am working with Python 3.6, and I am using [Canny Edge Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) to detect features inside the image. I understand that the algorithm for canny edge detection uses edge gradients to find edges. While Canny Edge Detection gives me features inside the retina scan for a proper choice of threshold values, it always keeps the circular rim between the retina scan and the black background in the output image.

**In the output image, I want to have only the features inside the image (retina scan), and not the outer rim. How can I do this?** I am searching for solutions which use Python. I am also open to the use of techniques other than Canny Edge Detection if they help to achieve the required task.

Below is the actual image, and the output image that I get from Canny Edge Detection.

[image]

Below is the circular rim that I am talking about (highlighted in red.)

[image]

Given below is the **expected output image**:

[image]

My code is given underneath:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread as imread

plt.figure(1)
img_DR = cv2.imread('img.tif',0)
edges_DR = cv2.Canny(img_DR,20,40)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img_DR)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges_DR,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

You can find the image used in this code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jwe13CHQtyyjmLRQCsP05haLEkadp8wL/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove features in unwanted positions after detection, e.g. with a precomputed mask.

Comment: Thanks for your post, Micka. Could you give more details of how I can implement your suggestion in the said problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the expected output should be? Are you trying to extract only the retina scan (gray sections) as a separate image and remove the black outer background?

Comment: Thanks for your post, nathancy. :) I have added expected output image now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could fix this in 3 steps:

1) Threshold your input image at a very low intensity, so your retina is the only foreground region. Looking at your image this should work just fine since you have no real black areas in your foreground region:

```
img = cv2.imread('retina.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,bin = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[image]

[image]

2) Use erosion to remove a small margin from your foreground, you want to remove the part where your outer rim artifacts develop after you apply canny:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(bin,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

[image]

(visualised in red: the eroded area)

3) Use this eroded image as a binary mask **on your current result image**. This will remove the outer border while keeping all inner structures intact:

```
edges_DR = cv2.Canny(img,20,40)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(edges_DR,edges_DR,mask = erosion)
```

[image]

[image]

You may have to experiment with the kernel size for the erosion to remove the full border but only the border. But generally, this should produce really good and robust results. Even if the orientation or size of your scan is not consistent.

Comment: edit: added some pictures and code to clarify the procedure

Comment: @T A : Thanks for your answer. Is your definition if `edges_DR` the same as what I had used in my question?